# Accessing different data sources depending on a parameter in one method

Tags: c#, refactoring

I've got a question on how I should solve/implement such issue:

Case:
*Depending on ID (coming in HTTP request) I need to get data from different repository / database table.*

I'm using a generic repository interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> 
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    // ...
}
```

The code that bugs me:

```
if (reportId == 2)
{
var repo = new Repository<EntityA>(_context);
var result = repo.GetAll().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == anotherId);

if (result == null)
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

}
else if (reportId == 3)
{
var repo = new Repository<EntityB(_context);
var result = repo.GetAll().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == anotherId);

if (result == null)
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
else if (reportId == 4)
{
var repo = new Repository<EntityC>(_context);
var result = repo.GetAll().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == anotherId);

if (result == null)
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
else
{
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

This code is ugly and there's a lot of repetitions.

I'm wondering what's the best approach for this issue.

I could possibly write different method for every case but this solution doesn't feel right
because it violates DRY method (as well as this 'hardcoded' solution).

Also having all this code (or method invocation) seems to be violating SRP and it should be separated.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may applying next refactoring (based on "extraction method"):

```
public T FindEntityById<T>(ContextClass _context, int anotherId)
{
    var repo = new Repository<T>(_context);
    return repo.GetAll().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == anotherId);
}

// ... next your method

object result = null;
switch(reportId)
{
    case 2:
        result = FindEntityById<EntityA>(_context, anotherId);
        break;
    case 3:
        result = FindEntityById<EntityB>(_context, anotherId);
        break;
    case 4:
        result = FindEntityById<EntityC>(_context, anotherId);
        break;
}
if (result == null) return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```